# Find shortest path visiting certain nodes in a grid

Tags: algorithm, grid, path-finding

I have a grid of 10*10 sqare nodes, and I would like to find a path for a robot that goes through an array of points.
I want the robot to spend the shortest time possible going through them (In whatever order)
Also it will start and end in a corner every time, but there will always be enouch time to turn in any way after the path is finished for the next path (It will do this repeatably)
The robot can't go diagonally, can only turn left and one turn takes the same time as going one space on the grid (I want to be able to generate the code for the robot for the "Karel the robot" language)
The finding doesn't need to be fast, just the following of it, but I just don't want do brute-force it.